# Table of contents page numbers wrong with includepdf and addtotoc and titling

Tags: table-of-contents, pdfpages

I'm using the `addtotoc` option from `includepdf` to add a TOC entry for two included PDFs. However, the table of contents always thinks they're on the first page (note that I have rebuilt the document enough times for the aux files to be read properly). Other similar answers on this site seem to suggest using `addtotoc`, but I'm already doing that (and have the same result if adding the contents line manually as shown in the example).

In this case I expect each document title to show up as an entry in the ToC at the correct page (eg. pages 1 and 220 or so in this specific example):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{book}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{titling}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}

% Add the title to the Table of Contents
% Has the same result as using the addtotoc option
% \renewcommand{\maketitlehooka}{\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\thetitle}}

\newcommand{\includerfc}[4]{
    \cleardoublepage
    \title{#1}
    \author{#2}
    \date{#3}
    \maketitle
    \cleardoublepage
    \includepdf[pages=-,addtotoc={1, chapter, 1, \thetitle, rfc:#4}]{rfc#4.pdf}
}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\includerfc{Extensible Messaging and Presence Protocol: Core}{P. Saint‐Andre}{March 2011}{6120}
\includerfc{Use of Transport Layer Security in the\\*Extensible Messaging and Presence Protocol}{P. Saint‐Andre\\T. Alkemade}{June 2015}{7590}
\end{document}
```

Is there something I can do to ensure that the page number is the actual page in the output PDF or isn't read until the external PDFs have been inserted?

The PDFs used in this example document are:

- https://tools.ietf.org/pdf/rfc6120.pdf
- https://tools.ietf.org/pdf/rfc7590.pdf

Comment: Difficult to compile this is, link to the `.pdf` files give you must ;-)

Comment: EDIT: Links added in the original question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR — `\maketitle` was resetting the page numbers.

After digging for a while I decided to go down the list and start commenting things out that seemingly hadnothing to do with the problem in case there were some funny side effects; in retrospect, maybe I should have started with this.

It turned out that when I commented out the `\maketitle`, everything worked fine. This led me to dig into the `titlepage` package so I started commenting out things there. Eventually I noticed that it worked when I got rid of the `titlepage` environment, so I dug into that and found it in the book class.

Turns out that the title page resets the line numbering (as you might expect since it should be the first page), and using the `titling` environment to insert multiple title pages does not change this behavior or give you a way to configure it (as far as I can see).